# Firebase cloud functions node.js code not returning data

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to node.js and firebase, I've written this code using firebase cloud functions.This function will trigger every time a new foodId is created and will return only newly created data..The function is deploying fine but when I'm inserting data in the database,it should show data on console but I'm getting the error shown in logs.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.onDataAdded = functions.database.ref('restaurants/restaurant1/Foods/{foodId}').onCreate((snapshot,context) => {
   const foodId = context.params.foodId;
   console.log(`This is my food Id ${foodId}`);
   const Mydata= snapshot.val();
  console.log(Mydata);
});
```

> logs: This is my food Id 04
>
> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Please help!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the details of what **exactly** you're doing that is supposed to trigger the function, and what you expect to be logged after the function triggers.

Comment: ^Edited! @DougStevenson

Comment: Understood the issue, Its working fine now, thanks ^^